# How to use addressing and validation PostCodeAnywhere on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, street-address

I'm building an application that takes the departure and destination address from the user. The company purchased Capture+ from PostCode anyWhere to be used on our website, I now need to build it on Android.

I'm trying to build a layout that would have something like this demo
http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/address-capture-software/try-it-now/

I tried to look for an Android API for that, but didn't find a Java API http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/support/sample-code.aspx

This link shows how to get started with Capture+ , but again only javascript and some html form
https://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/address-capture-software/guide/default.aspx?reg=1

I've tried reading about the search dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

But i'm not sure if it's the right thing, I'm really lost, can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the technical support team here at Postcode Anywhere. With the Capture+ function at the moment it can only be done with the JavaScript snippet provided in the integration process.

We do however have JAVA code samples for all our API calls which you can use to implement the more traditional 'Click to Find' method. All the APIs can be found here:

http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/address-validation/api/

For the UK the APIs that you require are the 'Find' and the 'Retrieve By ID'.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom, wow stackoverflow are really the best, didn't expect tech support to be on here lol I'll try the API's you showed and get back to you. Much Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Tom, got it all working, had to make API output a string array rather than a hashtable. But now that I've used too many finds, it's giving me a problem because I didn't use any retrieves, the thing is, I don't exactly need to use any retrieves, is it possible to use finds only without using retrieves ?

Answer (score 1):

No problem, good to hear you got it working.

The service is intended to be used in this two part method (Find and retrieve). The retrieve by ID is the call where the charge is made. There are restriction on how many 'Finds' that can be used when no 'Retrieves' are made.

If you want to drop me an email of your requirements I can have a look into the best way of doing it?

My email is tomm@postcodeanywhere.com

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Tom, ignore my previous comment, I figured that we need to use retrieve method, and I actually now need to use it anyway to get the postcode, and I also use geo services to get the Lat and Lng from the postcode, all works seamlessly perfect :D